# Javascript resize div width with calc

Tags: javascript, html

I'm running into an error with a javascript code I'm working on. I'm trying to make a collapsible sidebar. Whenever the user is hovering over the bar, the sidebar should be 280px wide and the main content should be `calc(100vw-280px)`. Alternatively, whenever the user is NOT hovering over the bar, the sidebar should be 80px wide and the main content should be `calc(100vw-80px)`.

This seems simple enough, but the `#content` div is not resizing whenever the function runs. The only thing I can figure is that javascript does not play friendly with `calc` but there could be something else I'm overlooking too in the CSS or with default values. I'm including all of the code just to be safe. Any help is appreciated!!

```js
var mini = true;

function toggleSidebar() {
  if (mini) {
    document.getElementById("rightbar").style.width = "280px";
    document.getElementById("content").style.width = "calc(100vw-280px)";
    this.mini = false;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("rightbar").style.width = "80px";
    document.getElementById("content").style.width = "calc(100vw-80px)";
    this.mini = true;
  }
}
```

```css
body {margin: 0; background-color: #F2F2F2;}

.topbar {
  z-index: 10;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  width: 100vw; height: 56px;
  font-size: x-large;
  background-color: #5B7042;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #3F5328}

#rightbar {
  z-index: 1;
  position: fixed;
  top: 60px; right: 0%;
  width: 80px; height: calc(100vh - 60px);
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  color: #412A1B;
  border-left: 2px solid darkgray}

#content {
  display: grid;
  position: fixed;
  top: 60px; left: 0;
  width: calc(100vw - 80px);
  height: calc(100vh - 60px);
  padding: 32px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  grid-auto-columns: 1fr; 
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 300px; 
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr; 
  gap: 20px 40px; 
  grid-template-areas: 
    "hello hello"
    "announce tasks"
    "announce tasks"
    "announce streak";}

  .hello {
    grid-area: hello;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 3em;
    color: #3F5328}

.announce {
  overflow: scroll;
  grid-area: announce}

.tasks {
  padding: 20px;
  grid-area: tasks;
  text-align: center;}

.something {grid-area: something}

.streak {
  grid-area: streak;
  font-size: 52px;
  font-weight: 800}

.module {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 6px;
  box-shadow: 3px 4px #CECECE}

table {width: 100%}

td {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;}

td .msg {
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 1.5}

.posted {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 42px 2fr 1fr;  
  grid-template-areas: 
    "pic author timestamp"}

.posted .img {grid-area: pic}

.posted .author {
  grid-area: author;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 16px;}

.posted .timestamp {
  grid-area: timestamp;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  color: gray;
  font-size: 16px}

.pic{
  width: 25px;
  clip-path: circle();}
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://classcolonies.com/resources/style.css'>

<div class='topbar'></div>

<div id='rightbar' onmouseover="toggleSidebar()" onmouseout="toggleSidebar()"></div>

<div id='content'>
  <div class='hello'>Hi, John.</div>
  <div class='module tasks center'><p>You have <b>10 tasks</b> to do this week.</p></div>
  <div class='module streak center'> 32</div>
  <div class='module announce'>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <span class='msg'>Please do not message me at the moment. I am trying to fix this horrible CSS glitch..</span>
          <div class='posted'>
            <span class='img'><img class='pic' src='https://mrdansby.com/resources/pics/1.png'></span>
            <span class='author'>Mr. Dansby</span>
            <span class='timestamp'>33m ago</span>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <span class='msg'>Have a great fall break!</span>
          <div class='posted'>
            <img class='pic' src='https://mrdansby.com/resources/pics/1.png'>
            <span class='author'>Mr. Dansby</span>
            <span class='timestamp'>1d ago</span>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <span class='msg'>Be sure to bring a pencil and paper to class tomorrow!</span>
          <div class='posted'>
            <img class='pic' src='https://mrdansby.com/resources/pics/1.png'>
            <span class='author'>Mr. Dansby</span>
            <span class='timestamp'>3d ago</span>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`calc` is a bit persnickety about whitespace.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc()#notes).  Specifically, the operator in the calc equation must have a space on either side.  I updated your `calc` JS setting lines from something like this...

```js
document.getElementById("content").style.width = "calc(100vw-280px)";
```

...to include the whitespace:

```js
document.getElementById("content").style.width = "calc(100vw - 280px)";
```

...and it seems closer to what I think you're looking for; see the snippet below:

```js
var mini = true;

function toggleSidebar() {
  if (mini) {
    document.getElementById("rightbar").style.width = "280px";
    document.getElementById("content").style.width = "calc(100vw - 280px)";
    this.mini = false;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("rightbar").style.width = "80px";
    document.getElementById("content").style.width = "calc(100vw - 80px)";
    this.mini = true;
  }
}
```

```css
body {margin: 0; background-color: #F2F2F2;}

.topbar {
  z-index: 10;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  width: 100vw; height: 56px;
  font-size: x-large;
  background-color: #5B7042;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #3F5328}

#rightbar {
  z-index: 1;
  position: fixed;
  top: 60px; right: 0%;
  width: 80px; height: calc(100vh - 60px);
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  color: #412A1B;
  border-left: 2px solid darkgray}

#content {
  display: grid;
  position: fixed;
  top: 60px; left: 0;
  width: calc(100vw - 80px);
  height: calc(100vh - 60px);
  padding: 32px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  grid-auto-columns: 1fr; 
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 300px; 
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr; 
  gap: 20px 40px; 
  grid-template-areas: 
    "hello hello"
    "announce tasks"
    "announce tasks"
    "announce streak";}

  .hello {
    grid-area: hello;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 3em;
    color: #3F5328}

.announce {
  overflow: scroll;
  grid-area: announce}

.tasks {
  padding: 20px;
  grid-area: tasks;
  text-align: center;}

.something {grid-area: something}

.streak {
  grid-area: streak;
  font-size: 52px;
  font-weight: 800}

.module {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 6px;
  box-shadow: 3px 4px #CECECE}

table {width: 100%}

td {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;}

td .msg {
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 1.5}

.posted {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 42px 2fr 1fr;  
  grid-template-areas: 
    "pic author timestamp"}

.posted .img {grid-area: pic}

.posted .author {
  grid-area: author;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 16px;}

.posted .timestamp {
  grid-area: timestamp;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  color: gray;
  font-size: 16px}

.pic{
  width: 25px;
  clip-path: circle();}
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://classcolonies.com/resources/style.css'>

<div class='topbar'></div>

<div id='rightbar' onmouseover="toggleSidebar()" onmouseout="toggleSidebar()"></div>

<div id='content'>
  <div class='hello'>Hi, John.</div>
  <div class='module tasks center'><p>You have <b>10 tasks</b> to do this week.</p></div>
  <div class='module streak center'> 32</div>
  <div class='module announce'>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <span class='msg'>Please do not message me at the moment. I am trying to fix this horrible CSS glitch..</span>
          <div class='posted'>
            <span class='img'><img class='pic' src='https://mrdansby.com/resources/pics/1.png'></span>
            <span class='author'>Mr. Dansby</span>
            <span class='timestamp'>33m ago</span>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <span class='msg'>Have a great fall break!</span>
          <div class='posted'>
            <img class='pic' src='https://mrdansby.com/resources/pics/1.png'>
            <span class='author'>Mr. Dansby</span>
            <span class='timestamp'>1d ago</span>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <span class='msg'>Be sure to bring a pencil and paper to class tomorrow!</span>
          <div class='posted'>
            <img class='pic' src='https://mrdansby.com/resources/pics/1.png'>
            <span class='author'>Mr. Dansby</span>
            <span class='timestamp'>3d ago</span>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I knew it would be something silly like that! I couldn't image for the life of me what was wrong. Thank you!!

Comment: Yeah, `calc` is a tricky one with that; it's burned me a few times.  Glad this helped!  Good luck, and happy coding!